# I can't see any icons in the dash

Tags: gui

I installed Ubuntu 14.04 but I'm not able to see any icons in the dash, *however* applications are still being launched properly.

Any suggestions to get back the icons??

Comment: Try `unity --reset` in terminal.

Comment: Ty Mitch. It worked properly. Just had to reboot it again.

Comment: Please answer your own question and then accept the answer so other users can find it as well...  ;-)

Comment: @Fabby give him a boost so he can.  Not a bad question.